# How to reorder dynamic string keys for dictionary to save it to JSON

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

How to sort the dynamic updated dictionary data every time new keys are updated in the dictionary? It gives me a random order for the keys whenever i try to print the dictionary after updating.

Using Sorted function doesn't seem to work in sorting the data dynamically. I keep getting random order whenever new keys are added to dictionary and i need to sort them and update them in JSON formatted data.

```
mydict ={"item_0": "apples"}
print(mydict)
mydict.update(item_1="banana")
print(mydict)
mydict.update(item_2="oranges")
print(mydict)
mydict.update(item_3="peaches")
print(mydict)
mydict.update(item_4="tangerines")
print(mydict)

Actual Results
{'item_0': 'apples'}
{'item_0': 'apples', 'item_1': 'banana'}
{'item_2': 'oranges', 'item_0': 'apples', 'item_1': 'banana'}
{'item_2': 'oranges', 'item_3': 'peaches', 'item_0': 'apples', 'item_1': 
'banana'}
{'item_4': 'tangerines', 'item_2': 'oranges', 'item_3': 'peaches', 
'item_0': 'apples', 'item_1': 'banana'}

Expected Results
{'item_0': 'apples'}
{'item_0': 'apples', 'item_1': 'banana'}
{'item_0': 'apples', 'item_1': 'banana', 'item_2': 'oranges'}
{'item_0': 'apples', 'item_1': 'banana', 'item_2': 'oranges', 'item_3': 
'peaches'}
{'item_0': 'apples', 'item_1': 'banana', 'item_2': 'oranges', 'item_3': 
'peaches', 'item_4': 'tangerines'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sorted` function something like this:

```
dict(sorted(mydict.items()))
```

Sample output:

```
>>> mydict={'item_2': 'apples', 'item_3': 'banana', 'item_0': 'oranges', 'item_1': 'peaches', 'item_4': 'tangerines'}
>>> mydict
{'item_2': 'apples', 'item_3': 'banana', 'item_0': 'oranges', 'item_1': 'peaches', 'item_4': 'tangerines'}
>>> dict(sorted(mydict.items()))
{'item_0': 'oranges', 'item_1': 'peaches', 'item_2': 'apples', 'item_3': 'banana', 'item_4': 'tangerines'}
```

Comment: Tried it. doesn't seem to work. Gives me the same output

Comment: Even sorted list of tuples when converted into dictionary lose their sorted property. Can't figure out why..                                                                            

    >>> dict([('item_0', 'apples'), ('item_1', 'banana'), ('item_2', 'oranges'), ('item_3', 
    'peaches'), ('item_4', 'tangerines')])
    {'item_4': 'tangerines', 'item_2': 'oranges', 'item_3': 'peaches', 'item_0': 'apples', 
    'item_1': 'banana'}

Comment: Do you need sort tuple?

Comment: I need sorted dictionary but sorted function returns a tuple and converting that tuple to dictionary just gives the same result. I just want this as result  {'item_0': 'apples', 'item_1': 'banana', 'item_2': 'oranges', 'item_3': 
'peaches', 'item_4': 'tangerines'}

Comment: I tried with you sample output and get result as you want. see my sample output

Answer (score 1):

Try sorted(mydict.items()) without the dict() function. This worked for me:

```
mydict ={"item_0": "apples"}
print(mydict)
mydict.update(item_1 = "banana")
print(mydict)
mydict.update(item_2 = "oranges")
print(mydict)
mydict.update(item_3 = "peaches")
print(mydict)
mydict.update(item_4 = "tangerines")
print(sorted(mydict.items()))
```

Comment: Yup that worked. Should work on the dynamic code too. Will try it out on the dynamic forms in the website.

Comment: Yup that works for sorting but the format of dictionary changes. It returns list of tuples like this [('item_0', 'apples'), ('item_1', 'banana'), ('item_2', 'oranges'), ('item_3', 'peaches'), ('item_4', 'tangerines')] and i might need the same format for it to be stored in JSON like this {'item_0': 'apples', 'item_1': 'banana', 'item_2': 'oranges', 'item_3': 
'peaches', 'item_4': 'tangerines'}